# Removing elements from a local data structure effects the parent object

Tags: c#

I have the following code where I am checking if some elements are not matching in my dictionary then I want to remove the unmatching elements from the local item. The problem is, When a value is removed from the collection, for some reason it also modifies the parental structure.

My other problem is, for example if I have list as "A","B","B", using the Except is only giving me the single B but not the other. Please help.

```
 public void AddLogs(IEnumerable<ReportGenerationTypes> subElements)
    {
                   var changeDetails = new Dictionary<AuditSaveHeader, List<string>>();
                    List<string> AuditableItems = null;
                    List<string> subItems = new List<string>();
                    foreach (var item in subElements)
                    {
                        subItems.Add(item.ToString());
                    }
                    foreach (var item in auditLogData?.AuditHeaders)
                    {
                        if (!changeDetails.ContainsKey(item))
                        {
                            changeDetails.Add(item, null);
                        }
                        AuditableItems = new List<string>();
                        foreach (var inner in item.AuditChangeValues)
                        {
                            AuditableItems.Add(inner.Auditable.ToString());
                        }
                        changeDetails[item] = AuditableItems;
                    }


                    for (int i = 0; i < changeDetails.Count; i++)
                    {

                            var result = kp.Value.Except(subItems);
                            Auditable AuditItem = Auditable.Unassigned;

                           //I think the problem lies with the below code not sure.
                            if (result != null && result.Count() > 0)
                            {
                                foreach (var item in result)
                                {
                                    Enum.TryParse(item, out AuditItem);
                                    var itemToRemove = kp.Key.AuditChangeValues.Where(x => x.Auditable == AuditItem).FirstOrDefault();
//The following line effects the AuditChangeValues object and not just my dictionary.                                    
kp.Key.AuditChangeValues.Remove(itemToRemove);
                                }
                            }
                     }

    }
```

Comment: "When a value is removed from the collection, for some reason it also modifies the parental structure." That sounds like you are running into call by reference mechanics. Two reference variables end up referencing the same thing in memory. If you learned this part of class mechanics with string, there is a bad news: String is one of the few classes that beahves differntly in this area.

Comment: Hmm ok I understand that string is a reference type. But in my case then how can I fix my problem. What value type can I use instead of List<string> as the Dictionary value?

Comment: You are using some vars that are not shown, like `kp`, `auditLogData`, etc. and overall is not clear what you want to achieve. Anyway I agree the problem is you are editing the reference to an object. You could try cloning the objects, etc. But without really understanding the code is hard to tell.

Comment: Sure thank you thats what I thought. I have to create a local object and clone it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Promoting my comment to answer:

You are using some vars that are not shown, like kp, auditLogData, etc. and overall is not clear what you want to achieve.

Anyway I agree the problem is you are editing the reference to an object. You could try cloning the objects, etc. But without really understanding the code is hard to tell.

Comment: Yes I did clone the object and it works just fine. Thank You.

Comment: Awesome! Glad to help :)